# How to split this text file by shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, split

I want to use the shell to split this file:

```
ID: xxx
Name: xxx
HW =
In-class = 
Comments:

ID: yyy
Name: yyyy
HW =
In-class = 
Comments:

ID: zzz
Name: Zzzz
HW =
In-class = 
Comments:
```

So each paragraph is saved to a file named `FILE01` which is in a folder that is the `ID` of the paragraph.

For example paragraph:

```
ID: zzz
Name: Zzzz
HW =
In-class = 
Comments:
```

Should be saved to the file `./zzz/FILE01`.

How can I do this?

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting, please check and [edit] if needed.

Comment: By "shell" do you actually mean *just* the shell, or would you be able to use utils that actually makes sense for this?

Comment: It because the file is used in linux and I know bash shell a little bit.. Can you make it by some other way?

Comment: What have you already tried?  What should happen if the 'ID' field isn't unique?  Are all the field values, limited to a single line or could they occupy more than a single line?

Comment: "ID" should be unique. The "comments" may have several lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this line pls:

```
 awk -v RS= '{print > "~/"$2"/FILE01"}' file
```

this assumes that those directories (`xxx, yyy,zzz`) are already there.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite easy with `awk`:

```
$ ls 
file

$ awk '{system("mkdir -p "$2); print > ($2"/FILE01")}' RS= file
```

Produces:

```
$ ls
file  xxx/  yyy/  zzz/

$ cat xxx/FILE01 
ID: xxx
Name: xxx
HW =
In-class =
Comments:

$ cat yyy/FILE01 
ID: yyy
Name: yyyy
HW =
In-class =
Comments:

$ cat zzz/FILE01 
ID: zzz
Name: Zzzz
HW =
In-class =
Comments:
```

Comment: +1 To avoid nasal demons if $2 contains globbing characters, you should quote it, i.e. `{system("mkdir -p \""$2"\""); print > ($2"/FILE01")}`.